# While using mod_rewrite what is the common practice to render right path to the img/css/js files?

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

On the one hand mod_rewrite allows me to make userfriendly urls redirecting requests to proper script but on the other I can't use relative links because they will point at nonexistent files.
A little example:
mod_rewrite redirects request
`http://site.ru/param/one/page.html`
at `http://site.ru/script.php`
while I have "myimg.jpeg" file at the same folder I can't use relative link `<img src="myimg.jpeg />` cause in that case the browser will try to load img from the "http://site.ru/param/one/myimg.jpeg" address.

While using mod_rewrite what is the common practice to render right path to the img/css/js files?

I have 2 ideas about the realization:
1) to add base tag like that `<base href="http://site.ru/" />`
2) to define a variable with the baseUrl and then use it while rendering src attributes like that:
`$baseUrl = 'http://site.ru/';
...
echo '<img src="' . $baseUrl . 'myimg.jpeg" />`

Which is the best solution and are there any other ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use relative URLs. In almost all cases, a `$baseUrl` variable is unnecessary - just reference things by their path from the site's root.

i.e. `<img src="/images/myimg.jpeg" />` instead of `<img src="images/myimg.jpeg" />`

Comment: thank you. quite impressive solution. wonder how i missed that

Comment: actually I thought leading slash doesn't make sense